# How to get y-axis inverted to share a common original point with x-axis for 3D plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to get the y-axis inverted to share a common original point with x-axis,the x-axis can be inverted, but the y-axis can be set like x-axis,so could any one give me some suggestions?the wanted result is shown in the picture.

```
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
ax = plt.gca(projection = '3d')
ax.set_title('3d_image_show')

ax.set_xlabel('X')  
ax.set_ylabel('Y')  
ax.set_zlabel('Z')  
ax.view_init(elev=20, azim=45)
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL2IR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Change azim to `-135` (comes from `45-180`, `45` is from your code), and no need to invert the axes.

```
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca(projection = '3d')
ax.set_title('3d_image_show')

ax.set_xlabel('X')  
ax.set_ylabel('Y')  
ax.set_zlabel('Z')  
ax.view_init(elev=20, azim=-135)
```

output:
[image]